# Android AnalogClock

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, clock

Hi i want to draw the clock which only have seconds tick its just a circle and a line and this line rotate wrt any vertex..

```
    Paint myPaint = new Paint();
    myPaint.setColor(Color.rgb(0, 0, 0));
    myPaint.setStrokeWidth(10);
    canvas.drawCircle(50, 100, 50, myPaint);

    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setColor(Color.rgb(250, 250, 250));
    p.setStrokeWidth(2);

    canvas.drawLine(50,100,50,60,p);
```

Now how do i rotate the above line please help its an android java project working in Android studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rotate the line (startX, startY) and (endX, endY) individually or you can rotate the canvas itself (which I think it is easier).

Using your example:

```
    Paint myPaint = new Paint();
    myPaint.setColor(Color.rgb(0, 0, 0));
    myPaint.setStrokeWidth(10);
    canvas.drawCircle(50, 100, 50, myPaint);

    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setColor(Color.rgb(250, 250, 250));
    p.setStrokeWidth(2);

    float angle = 45;
    canvas.save();
    canvas.rotate(angle, 50, 100);

    canvas.drawLine(50,100,50,60,p);

    canvas.restore();
```